# Send commands to a minecraft server over java

Tags: java, multithreading, process

Hi I'd like to send commands to a running minecraft server and watch it's response.
everything works fine but after the server starts I'm not able to send any commands:

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server{
    private String name;
    private StartCommand command;
    private boolean on = false;
    private Process p = null;

    public Server(StartCommand c, String name){
        this.command = c;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void start(){
    try {
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.getCommand());
      System.out.println("Server: " + name + " is on now!");
      on = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      on = false;
    }
  }

  public void watch(){
   System.out.println("threads:");
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new proc1(p));
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new proc2(p));
   System.out.println("start1");
   t1.start();
   System.out.println("start2");
   t2.start();
 }
}


  //-----Processes-----//

class proc1 implements Runnable{
  private Process p;
  private static String line = null;

  public proc1(Process p){
    this.p = p;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    try{

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
     }
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      //on = false;
  }
}
}

class proc2 implements Runnable{
  private Process p;

  public proc2(Process p){
    this.p = p;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    //OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("start while (type commands now!!!!)");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
      String command = in.nextLine();

      if(command.equals("ext")){
           //coming soon
        return;
      }else{
       try{
         out.write(command);
         out.flush();
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return;
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I know there must be sth. wrong in my proc2 class. It's actually the first time I'm using the 'Process' class

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried sending hard-coded events? Because if no, this is a possibility to refine the problem into "UI input" and "command sending".

Comment: not sure what you mean by hard-coded events but I tried to use a String instead of System.in in my Scanner

Comment: Pretty sure he means try just sending a string like "example command" to the server to see if it reacts.

Comment: yup I tried that but the server does not respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Scanner.next() to retrieve the next command.  Are you sure that's what you want to do? That would read everything separated by a space as a separate input, and write it WITHOUT the spaces (delimiters are deleted).

EG: "/give player item" would come out as "/giveplayeritem" either mashed together on a single line with no return at the end, or "/give\nplayer\nitem" depending on how you have the buffered output set up to send commands to the server.

EDIT:
The fix that worked can be seen in his self-answer.

Basically, the flushes weren't working correctly, and using a printwriter which automatically flushes on a println then flushing against somehow fixes that.

Comment: oh.. it has to be nextLine(). I'll edit this in my post. but unfortunately this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Does the output you tried have a new line in it? like "command \n"

Comment: yup As you can see in my proc2 class every output goes in System.out.println(line);. but this class works perfectly fine. when I start the Server, my app posts the correct server output.

Comment: You mean proc1? and I'm talking about out.write()
have you tried putting an out.newline() after?  Or am I looking at the wrong place entirely.

Comment: proc1 sry. yes I think you are looking at the wrong place. proc1 works (it looks like it's working). The mistake is in proc2. I think the server does not get any of my input-commands.

Comment: hmm, what happens when you call out.close() after sending text? does that change anything?

Comment: WOW that works but when I want to run another command it throws an IOException because the stream is closed. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I wanted to see if closing the buffer would fix the problem. You're getting an error because you're now trying to write to a closed buffer stream. So for some reason, something is storing your input between the processes.

Comment: Ideally we would find out what is buffering between them, rather than closing the stream.

Comment: Of course you could always just reopen the stream for every input, as inefficient as it would be.

Comment: Ok I understand. If you need more infos or the rest of my code, just ask.

Comment: If no one can find a better solution I'll have to do that.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I think you can't reopen a BufferedWriter. If so, how?

Comment: Can you try just using the outputstreamwriter instead of wrapping it in the bufferedwriter? The point of using a bufferedwriter is to prevent frequenty outputstreamwriter character conversions, but since you want to be sending the commands immediately every time you read them, there isn't really a point to it.

Comment: Same problem. :( But when I'm closing my outputstreamwriter It works again.

Comment: can you try with a printwriter wrapper, and just use the println() method? Shouldn't require a flush or close.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like it's working fine now, but I had to use the flush() method.

Here is my new code. I hope I have implemented everything the right way:

```
class proc2 implements Runnable{
  private Process p;

  public proc2(Process p){
    this.p = p;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("start while (type commands now!!!!)");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
      String command = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("test: " + command);

      if(command.equals("ext")){
           //FILL IN
           return;
      }else{
    //try{
      out.println(command);
      out.flush();
      /*out.flush();
      out.close();*/
    /*} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
        }*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should I leave it as it is now? Or is there still a better way?

Comment: FYI, its generally good form to give the person who helped you fix it credit for answering the question.